# Linear Algebra Hoffman Kunze Chapter 3 example 5!

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $R$ be the field of real numbers and let $V$ be the space of all functions from $R$ into $R$ which are continuous. Define T by $(Tf)(x)=\int^{x}_{0}f(t)dt$.

Then $T$ is a linear transformation from $V$ into $V$.

---

The last statement is not true, let $g$ be the zero function ($g(x)=0$, for any $x$).
$(Tg)(x)$ is equal to a class of functions in $V$ of the form $B_{c}(x)=c$. So, there is no unique assignment for a certain function from $V$.

Am I wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Tg$ is not a class of functions of a specific form; we can evaluate $Tg$ explicitly:

$$(Tg)(x) = \int_0^x 0 dt = 0 |_0^x = 0 - 0 = 0$$

Keep in mind that this is a *definite* integral, so there is not an arbitrary constant that needs to be added.

Comment: But, no, the antiderivative of $0$ is not $0$, it is the constant function.

Comment: @user68659 When evaluating a *definite* integral, we can choose any particular antiderivative. Since all the antiderivatives are all the same up to addition of a constant $c$, the subtraction upon evaluating limits removes the constant.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but then, it would be better to write that $\int^{x}_{0}0dt=r|^{x}_{0}$, where r is any antiderivative of $0$.

Comment: @user68659 You can, but it's an unnecessary complication.

Comment: The notation you used, $f|^{x}_{0}$ means that f is the antiderivative. That is what the notation means.

Comment: @user68659 Any one of the set of antiderivatives can be used there, and I simply chose the simplest one. There's no need to add an arbitrary constant in this case.

Comment: Yeah, actually, you're right... I did not think of it in that way.